# Proving the density theorem without assuming that $x>0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove this theorem:

> "If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers with $x < y$, then there exists an irrational number $z$ such that $x < z <y$."

I have to do the proof without assuming $x > 0$. My question is, if $x < 0$ can I just take $-x$ and apply the same proof as the book?

The proof in the book is something like this:
It is no loss of generality to assume that $x > 0$. Since $y - x > 0$, it follows from Corollary 2.4.5 that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/n < y - x$. Therefore, we have $nx + 1 < ny$. If we apply Corollary 2.4.6 to $nx > 0$, we obtain $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m - 1 ≤ nx < m$. Therefore, $m ≤ nx + 1 < ny$, whence $nx < m < ny$. Thus, the rational number $r := m/n$ satisfies $x < r < y$.

Comment: The statement you've written asks for an *ir*rational number! Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The application of Corollary $2.4.6$ is the only place where this sign of $x$ is directly exploited. Following the same argument:

Suppose $x<y$ and $x<0$. Then $y-x >0$ is still true. So by Corollary $2.4.5$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\frac{1}{n} < y-x$ or equivalently $nx+1<ny$. Now applying Corollary $2.4.6$ to $-nx > 0$ gives us the existence of $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m-1 \le -nx < m$. This directly implies that $-m \le nx < -m+1$. Also observe from this inequality that $-m+1 \le nx+1 < ny$.  All in all have that $nx < -m+1  <ny$. So $r:= \frac{-m+1}{n}$ is the rational number you are looking for.